# Is it possible to Post a Message to Teams Conversation using the SharePoint ClientContext?

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model, csom, microsoft-teams

I was successfully able to add a File in the Files tab of Teams, using the SharePoint.Client.ClientContext

But I could not find any documentation on posting a message using the clientContext.

Any help would be much appreciated.
I cant register an app, using the app registration page or use the app catalog, since I am only a contributor to the site.

I am allowed to use a Windows.Forms or desktop or console app

Answer (score 1):

APIs for Microsoft Teams in the Graph only support sending messages to channels, not to users (private chat).

As you can [see here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/chatmessage?view=graph-rest-beta), only channels operations are listed out. If you wish to send message to channel then you can [check here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)

Comment: thanks for your answer, yes, I want to post to a channel, but using the Client Context....Is their a way to get the Authenticated Graph Client using the SharePoint Client Context?

Comment: Kindly check here...https://www.tatvasoft.com/blog/overview-of-users-groups-and-permissions-in-microsoft-graph-part-2/

Comment: If you are working with SPFx then you just need to provide permission in both Application & Graph API admin centers. Then after it will take current logged in user's context in code so you can authenticate GraphClient.